# How to configure Ext GWT with GWT Designer?

Tags: gwt, gxt, gwt-designer

I have problem with configuration GXT with GWT Designer. I have all new releases of Eclipse, GWT plugin and GXT and cannot configure GXT to work with GWT Designer. I setup my project so that I can compile my GXT project and run it in browser.
However I can't design in GWT Designer. I don't see any GXT widget in GWT Designer.
All forums reffer to Google Web Toolkit -> Configure for using Ext-GWT (GXT) but I don't have this option.
I have done all steps defined in setup.txt of GXT.
The only thing that is not working is GWT designer do not see GXT widgets.

Regrads,

Comment: Yes, I have the same question as Adriano. It complains about gxt.jar and if you try to rename the gxt3.0.0beta1.jar to gxt.jar, it complains about the missing "resources" folder... Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Folks:

It simply appears that GXT 3 is *not* supported in the latest version of Windowbuilder. Period. All the instructions given in this thread work well for GXT 2, but GXT 3 has radical differences (different styling mechanisms, for one thing!) that Windowbuilder cannot seem to handle.

This is a bug that needs to be fixed in Windowbuilder.

Comment: Is it fixed now?

Answer (score 1):

I see this is an old article, but might still help people with the same problem.
If you right click on your gwt.xml file, the options are visible, if you click on your project, the options are not visible.  That's the problem I was having.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem. I solved by installing:

(If you are using Eclipse Indigo) 
http://dl.google.com/eclipse/inst/d2gwt/latest/3.7

Just check for the version you have. That should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

1. "select your GWT module file and right-click to select the Google Web Toolkit > Configure for using Ext GWT (GXT)" http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/tools/gwtdesigner/features/gwt/gxt.html
2. Read setup.txt in ext-gwt zip:

STEP 1 -> Create a Google Web Application Project project within Eclipse.

Copy the contents of the /resources folder in the download to a {foldername} location within your war folder.
Substitute {foldername} with the name of the folder you've created for resources within your war folder.

STEP 3 -> Add the following stylesheet to your host page.

STEP 3b -> If you are using Charts, add the following script to your host page.

STEP 4 -> Add the following entry to you projects module xml file.

STEP 5 -> Eclipse Setup (should be similar for other development environments)
These instructions assume you have a existing project and launch configuration.

1. Add gxt.jar to the project.
   a. Right click on project name in 'Package Explorer'.
   b. Select 'Properties' from content menu.
   c. Select 'Java Build Path'.
   d. Select 'Libraries' tab.
   e. Add the gxt.jar either with 'Add JARs...' or 'Add External JARs...'.
2. Add GXT jar to launch configuration.
   a. Choose Run / Open Run Dialog.
   b. Select your appropriate launch configuration under 'Java Application'.
   c. Select the 'Classpath' tab.
   d. Add the gxt.jar to the classpath.

Comment: Yes I have done all steps defined in setup.txt My application can run but only GWT Designer is not configured. I do not see widgets from Ext GWT. MOreover there is no "Google Web Toolkit > Configure for using Ext GWT (GXT)" in my Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

that happened to me too. I had to install WindowBuilder Pro from the update site (you can found it [here](http://code.google.com/intl/es-ES/javadevtools/download-wbpro.html)) and after that the  "Google Web Toolkit > Configure for using Ext GWT (GXT)" option appeared.

Answer (score 0):

Support for 3rd party components like GXT and SmartGWT is only available in the full version of GWT Designer available here...

http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/tools/download-gwtdesigner.html

Install the full version and then follow the instructions here...

http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/tools/gwtdesigner/features/gwt/gxt.html

Comment: Didn't work for me, please see my answer. Is this maybe a bug?

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem. The only way I got it working is this:

- I installed the full version of GWT designer as recommended by Eric Clayberg's answer (http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/tools/download-gwtdesigner.html)
- However, the instructions at http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/tools/gwtdesigner/features/gwt/gxt.html didn't work, because there simply isn't any "Google Web Toolkit > Configure for using Ext GWT (GXT)" for me either.

So instead, I created a new Project, using: New Project > WindowBuilder/GWT Designer/Model/GWT Java Project:

- I went through the Wizard, clicked Finish, and then it asked me about a GXT installation. The important thing is: You must select this **now**, I don't see *any* way to add this later. So navigate to a GXT installation folder. In that folder, I had to rename my "gxt-*.jar" to "gxt.jar" first, otherwise it couldn't be found (!).
- Now, when opening a Java file using "Open With > GWT Designer", and selecting the Design view tab at the bottom of the editor - voila, the GXT menus appear.