# Ext-Gwt gui designer

Tags: gwt, gxt, gui-designer

guys!
I am very interested with ext gwt. Do you know any darg and drop designers for this framework?
Does ext gwt work with ext designer?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Ext GWT won't work with Ext Designer. It will, however, work with GWT Designer in Eclipse.

Instructions:
http://code.google.com/intl/en-US/webtoolkit/tools/gwtdesigner/features/gwt/gxt.html

Some people had problems with that one, in that case you might find a workaround here:
[How to configure Ext GWT with GWT Designer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203594/how-to-configure-ext-gwt-with-gwt-designer)

And the last word from me: I haven't used that, working with GXT components the old fashioned way isn't a big pain, too.